# Авторизация

Tags: php

Ошибка в том, что когда я ввожу хоть и правильный логин и пароль мне выводит "Неверный Логин или пароль" подскажите пожалуйста ошибку, вот код:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('') or die("can't connect");
mysql_select_db(refresh615) or die(mysql_error());
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) {
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
  header("location:page.php");
}
else{  
echo "Неверный Логин или Пароль";
}

?>
```

Comment: С каких пор делается query по query??

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: Да тут лол-же...

     mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
     if($count==1) {
          // уже щас понятно что это НИКОГДА не выполнится
     }

Comment: Это не лол это "быдлокод 2.0" :DDD - "Забыдлячим авторизацию!" :DDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот по такому принципу функциклирует у меня работа с БД (Хотя коннект можно открыть единожды, я делаю это при каждом обращении к БД).
Нас отсюда будет интересовать функция do_login.

Данный пример удобен так-как имеет достаточно простой подход к его расширению.
P.S. Есть несколько лишних функций, но я их решил оставить для наглядности.
+ блок с авторизацией я оставил тоже как есть..... ну просто так )))

```
abstract class i_storage_service {
    abstract public function get_query($c);
}

abstract class i_storage_manager {
    private $_ss;

    public function __construct(i_storage_service $ss) {
        $this->_ss = $ss;
    }
    public function query($val) {
        return $this->_ss->get_query($val);
    }
}

class Storage extends i_storage_service {
    private static $DB_L = "login";
    private static $DB_P = "passwd";
    private static $DB_B = "db_name";
    private static $DB_H = "host";

    public function get_query ($query) {        
        $mysql_connect = mysql_connect(self::$DB_H, self::$DB_L, self::$DB_P);
        mysql_select_db(self::$DB_B, $mysql_connect);
        mysql_query('SET NAMES "UTF-8"');
        if(!$return = mysql_query($query)) {    
            trace_log("Storage service error : \"" . mysql_error()) . "\""; //Моя глобальная функция логирования
            mysql_close($mysql_connect);
            return false;
        }   
        mysql_close($mysql_connect);
        return $return;
    }
}
class User extends i_storage_manager {
    private $user = NULL;
    public function get_by_id($val) {
        $res = parent::query("SELECT * from `users` WHERE `id`=" . $val);
        (!$res) ? false : $this->user = mysql_fetch_object($res);
        return $this->user;
    }
    public function get_by_login($val) {
        $res =  parent::query("SELECT * from `users` WHERE `login`='".$val . "'");
            (!$res) ? false : $this->user = mysql_fetch_object($res);
        return $this->user;
    }
    public function do_login($l,$p="") {
        $res = NULL;
        if (!$l)
            return false;
        if ($p)
            $p = md5($p);
        else 
            $p = "";
        $res = parent::query("SELECT * from `users` WHERE `login`='" .$l . "' && `password`='".$p."'");
        if ($res) {
            if(!$res = mysql_fetch_object($res)){   
                trace_log("Error started session by login \"".$l."\" . Remote IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                return false;
            }
            $this->user = $res;
            trace_log("Session started by login \"".$res->login."\" . Remote IP: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        }
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

А вот и авторизация:

```
$Storage = new Storage;
$User = new User($Storage);

if($res = $User->do_login( $login, $passwd ))
    $json = json_encode(array('login' => true));
else 
    $json = json_encode(array('err' => 'login incorrect'));
```

Кстати, в $res вернется вся необходимая инфа о пользователе (если, конечно, авторизация будет успешной, а так будет false)

Comment: Вы не [этим](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/hello_world_in_patterns) впечатлились?)

Comment: Так это же стандартный подход :))) Паттерны...
Но моего паттерна тут не описано :)
Да и это еще мелочи :))) Модуль ядра проверки шаблонов "телефон, мыло, адрес etc.... " умиляет :)))

Comment: Это все чудесно, но это **явно** не уровень ТСа ^_^

Comment: А что есть ТС ?? :))

Answer (score 0):

Так и хочется сказать: "Ну, ты и [[@Prikol](/users/3015/prikol)](/users/3015/prikol)!", но я этого делать не буду.
Уберите первый `mysql_query`, оставьте просто строку.

Comment: Все-равно сказал, не напрямую, но тем не менее ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

mysql_connect('') or die("can't connect");
mysql_select_db(refresh615) or die(mysql_error());
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
if(mysql_result($sql),0)==1)
{
$sql=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

  session_register($sql[username]);
  session_register($sql[password]);
  header("location:page.php");
}
else{  
echo "Неверный Логин или Пароль";
}

?>
```

Comment: шото страшное понаписывали :DDD

Comment: Вы проверяли  хотя бы "username='$username' and password='$password'" ? Уверен вы ожидали другого результата

Comment:     $name='John';
    $var="Hello '$name'";
    echo $var; //Выведет: Hello 'John'

Comment: @Error, к чему это?

Comment: @Александр Маслов, проверяйте плз хотя бы в IDE, что пишете. `$sql[username]`, где вы видете объявление константы username? `session_register($sql[username]);` - это [что за](http://ru.php.net/session_register) анархия вообще?

Comment: К тому что нужно ' ' из запроса убрать

Comment: С чего это их нужно убрать, вы хотите отправить запрос со строкой без кавычек?) 

    SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=query ololo and password=12345 @#!%x25m;

Так что ли?

Comment: Вы правы походу , ошибся глупо .